# Where to mount and unmount inside an Enzyme describe function?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, enzyme

I'm trying to get the hang of testing components in a React project. I have a single test file on a single component so far, and I'm trying to prepare this file as a test suite with multiple tests in it.

```
import React from 'react';
import Enzyme, { mount } from 'enzyme';
import Adapter from 'enzyme-adapter-react-16';
import HamburgerIcon from './HamburgerIcon';

Enzyme.configure({ adapter: new Adapter() });

describe('<HamburgerIcon />', () => {

  const hamburgerIcon = mount(<HamburgerIcon showOverlay={showOverlay} />);

  it('displays on mobile', () => {
     ...
     ...
  });

  it('has class .open after click', () => {
    ...
    ...
  });

  hamburgerIcon.unmount();

});
```

I've removed the guts of the two tests, but basically the two tests are wrapped inside of a `describe` function, and I'm trying to `mount` the component once and `unmount` the component once in an effort to keep things DRY (don't repeat yourself).

I've placed the `mount` before the two `it` functions, thinking that mounting the component before running tests makes logical sense.

I placed the `unmount` after the two test functions, which causes the error:

> **Method “simulate” is meant to be run on 1 node. 0 found instead.**

I think this is happening because the component is unmounting before the tests are actually run.

If I `mount` and `unmount` in both tests, like this...

```
describe('<HamburgerIcon />', () => {

  it('displays on mobile', () => {
     const hamburgerIcon = mount(<HamburgerIcon showOverlay={showOverlay} />);
     ...
     ...
     hamburgerIcon.unmount();
  });

  it('has class .open after click', () => {
    const hamburgerIcon = mount(<HamburgerIcon showOverlay={showOverlay} />);
    ...
    ...
    hamburgerIcon.unmount();
  });

});
```

...the tests pass.

This seems excessive, though. What if my test suite has ten test functions it? Should I be mounting and unmounting like this for every single test?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use beforeEach and afterEach functions to set-up and clear your test.

```
afterEach(() => {
    //do the unmounting and other stuff here
    //this will be called after each test case
});

beforeEach(() => {
    //do the mounting and setting up the test case here
    //this will be called before each test case
});
```